# ScalaTest - type checking with upper type bounds

Tags: scala, testing, scalatest

Is it possible to prove the incorrectness of the following chunk of code with ScalaTest?

```
class A
class B[T <: A]
class C extends B[Any]
```

scalac will give the following error message...

> error: type arguments [Any] do not conform to class B's type parameter bounds [T <: A]

... but running the following test will result in a TestFailedException.

```
class MySpec extends FlatSpec with Matchers {
  "ScalaTest" should "detect type errors" in {
    """
      trait A
      class B[T <: A]
      class C extends B[Any]
    """ shouldNot typeCheck
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm quite perplexed as well.  I use `illTyped` from [shapeless](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless) to perform this checking at compile time, and it fails to catch this error as well.  I could only believe there is a Scala standard library/scalac issue at play here.

Comment: I think it is a bug either in ScalaTest or even in Scala itself. However, I was able to find a workaround. I already opened an issue on ScalaTest and posted an example there.